# versioning tool for nodejs

Tags: node.js, versioning, maven-release-plugin, agvtool

There are solutions to increment the version number in different application. Cocoa apps have agvtool and maven has the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/)  which increments the version number on releases. Are there similar tools for nodejs?

Answer (score 2):

I think such a tool seems excessively heavy-handed when the only thing you need to do to increment the version number in Node.js is something as simple as:

```
sed -i 's/0.1.2/0.2.4/' package.json
```

Will change the version for your Node.js package?

If you're talking about something that will deploy your code when you explicitly mark a new version, I'd be more inclined to use [git hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) and write a script to detect when a git tag is created and then start the deployment process.

You could use the `pre-applypatch` hook to detect when a tag is being created to run the `sed` script listed above and run `npm publish` for you automatically, but again, I don't see the point of having a heavyweight tool handle all of that when it's a simple script away (and said script could be written in Node.js, too!)

Comment: I wouldn't use that `sed` invocation to change the version because the string `0.1.2` might appear in the dependencies. It would be better to parse the JSON and then do `.version="0.2.4"` and then stringify.

Comment: Yes and no. You probably should use the full qualification, ``version: "0.1.2",`` but since the ``package.json`` format is fully defined and the ``version`` field is unambiguous in the definition, I don't see the point of a full JSON parse and stringify.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most correct answer is to use [`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version).

For example, to increment the major version of your package:

```
npm version major
```

This will increment the major version of your package and if it is a git repository it will also commit that change and create a tag of the same name of the version.

Follow up with:

```
git push
git push --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

[grunt-bump](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump) provides version bumping, as well as git tagging/commit/push. There are similar packages for other build tools such as `gulp-bump`.

Similar functionality is also now available with [`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version), but with fewer configuration options.